# Select a number of columns in an excel table for advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I have created raw data within a table, I use an advanced filter by VBA
but when I run the codes, the table disappeared so I try to write a code to select many columns but I received an error every time I tried

The code

```
'Assuming the name of the table is "RawData"
LastTransRow = Sheet9.ListObjects("RawData").DataBodyRange(19999, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Transaction Row
Sheet9.ListObjects("RawData").DataBodyRange("G1:A" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheet11.Range("A2:B3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet11.Range("K2:E19999"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: Your code worked here. Try removing this piece of code: `("G1:A" & LastTransRow)` because DataBodyRange has its range defined when the ListObject was defined. There is no need to calculate these limits.

Comment: But how can I restrict my range to just from ( Ato G ). I mean that the raw data range ( from A to T columns ) and I need to make advanced filter from A to G

Comment: Do you want do filter unique items in a partial DataBodyRange rows of the ListObject?

Comment: You want to filter partial DataBodyRange columns. That's fine. The raw data goes from A to T and you want to apply the advanced filter from A to G. But the raw data extends from Row1 to Row__ ? It could be that when calculating lngLastRow you are covering more data than you really want. Because most likely the 20 thousand rows can exceed your table limits.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the error that is happening? What is the description of this error? What line of code does it happen on?

Comment: Well, actually, I want to create Filter advanced unique  , from a table called (Raw data ) ( the raw data table range : A to T ) ( and the raws of this table extend to 9999  ) in the advanced filter , I want to export the information from column ( A) to ( G) to another table according to advanced filter criteria , the problem that I suffered from is that after I had run this code , the raw data table was converted to a range where this effect the pivot table that depend on the raw data table

Comment: so how I go through this , I need to explain in the VBA to export the data from [ raw data table ] but without converting to range and  staying as a table to avoid effecting the pivot table

Comment: I ran the macro and, as I expected, the ListObject was not mischaracterized, that is, it was not transformed into an Interval. You can verify that RawData is indeed a Table name by going into Excel's Name Manager and filtering the contents by 'Table Names'. I even manually applied an advanced filter by filtering on the Table itself (ListObject) and yet it continued to be reported as a ListObject. Only the filters were turned off. Referring to a table cell in the same row (in a cell outside the Table), standard ListObject notation is suggested (eg =RawData[@Column3])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added references to the Workbook that contains the code (ThisWorkbook) in order to ensure that operations are performed on its child sheets. Reset some arguments (eg: "G1:A" >>> "A1:G", "K2:E19999" >>> "E2:K19999"). Worked on my machine. Give it a try.

```
Sub AdvFilterTest()
    Dim LastTransRow As Long

    'Assuming the name of the table is "RawData"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
        .Activate
        LastTransRow = .ListObjects("RawData").DataBodyRange(19999, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Transaction Row
        .ListObjects("RawData").DataBodyRange.Range("A1:G" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A2:B3"), CopyToRange:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("E2:K19999"), Unique:=True

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Another thought: modify the above code I posted, commenting out the `.Activate` line. Then manually select sheet11 and run the code. When setting up an advanced filter, it is ideal to do so with the target sheet initially selected, so that Excel does not return an error message saying that you can only filter data for the same sheet. This can be observed in the macro recorder, doing the same operation, having each of the sheets selected at a time.

Comment: None of these tests with macro influenced the PivotTable I built.